# Moving a tag on a remote repo

Tags: git, version-control

I created a tag in my local repo and pushed it to a remote one. Then I found some additional changes that belonged with that tag. So I commited the changes and moved the tag in my local repo. Now the tag is empty on the remote repo. How do I update the tag on the remote repo to point to the same commit that it does in my local repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push origin tag_name`

if the change of tag is non-fast-forward, add force option

`git push -f origin tag_name`

Answer (score 1):

Note that [git1.8.2 mentions](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1443021) will impose the use of the --force (-f) option:

> "`git push $there tag v1.2.3`" used to allow replacing a tag `v1.2.3` that already exists in the repository $there, if the rewritten tag you are pushing points at a commit that is a decendant of a commit that the old tag `v1.2.3` points at.
>
> This was found to be error prone and starting with this release, any attempt to update an existing ref under `refs/tags/` hierarchy will fail, without "`--force`".